# Availability of resource dictionaries in a MEF solution

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am creating a Silverlight application that uses MVVM and MEF.  In the main project's app.xml file I have specified resource dictionaries:

```
    <Application   
  x:Class="RAP.App"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:app="clr-namespace:RAP"
  xmlns:telerikControls="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls" 
  xmlns:Resources="clr-namespace:RAP.Assets.Resources" 
  Startup="Application_Startup"
  UnhandledException="Application_UnhandledException">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/StylesX.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Styles.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <app:ApplicationResources x:Key="ApplicationResources" />
                    <app:NotOperatorValueConverter x:Key="NotOperatorValueConverter" />
                                        <app:IsNullConverter x:Key="IsNullConverter" />
                    <Resources:ResourceWrapper x:Key="ResourceWrapper" />
                                        <telerikControls:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
                                        <telerikControls:InvertedBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="InvertedBooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

In the main project, StaticResource references to items in the resource dictionaries resolve properly, but in the subsequent projects whose xap's are dynamically loaded, at design time, StaticResource references are unresolved and cause xaml designer load problems.  I thought that by specifying the resource dictionaries in the main project's app.xml, the resource dictionaries would be available for all of the projects in the solution.  Is there something else that I need to do to expose the resource dictionaries to the rest of the solution's projects?